# Enjin API (JSON) to PHP

Tags: php, json, api

I'm trying to get data from:

```
http://natomilcorp.com/api/get-users
```

But when I try it nothing is working.

```
$url = "http://natomilcorp.com/api/get-users";
$jsonString = file_get_contents($url);
$obj = json_decode($jsonString);
echo $obj->"username";
```

I try JQuery but I was not able to make it work.

I will like to get the `username`, `lastseen` and `datejoined`.

If someone could help me with this.

Comment: Use `$obj = json_decode($jsonString, true);` to create an array instead of an object and then do `print_r($obj);` to see the "structure". Finally you just need to use something like `echo($obj['200159']['username']);`.

Comment: Use `$obj->username` instead of `$obj->"username"`.

Comment: @HamZa an array isn't going to have any benefit over an object here, it's apples and apples for this question. OP - take the quotes out of username to start, and youll need to look over the results because there isn't just one username - there's lots.

Answer (score 0):

The things that could have gone wrong are:

1. The website is not responding
2. The JSON is invalid
3. There is some error in your code

This code should tell your what is happening:

```
error_reporting(-1); // Turn on error reporting
$url = "http://natomilcorp.com/api/get-users";
$jsonString = file_get_contents($url);
if ( ! $jsonString) {
    die('Could not get data from: '.$url);
}
$obj = json_decode($jsonString);
if ( ! $obj) {
    // See the following URL to figure out what the error is
    // Be sure to look at the comments, as there is a compatibility
    // function there
    // http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php
    die('Something is wrong with the JSON');
}
echo $obj->"username";
```